# Unable to run call subprocess method using python 3.2

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I have Python 3.2 installed, and i am trying to use the subprocess module, but i keep getting errors.

The code i am using is :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)
```

i keep getting the following error for `subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 514, in check_output
    process = Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 744, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 977, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and for the line `subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)` i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 521, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: The second one is absolutely clear: you tell the shell to exit with status 1, and you use `check_output()` which raises an exception upon non-zero exit codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem in not with `subprocess` -- the problem is there is *no* executable named `echo` on the *PATH*:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My *guess* is `echo` is a Windows Shell internal command. Try to launch it with `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"], shell=True)
```

If you want to call an executable program (".exe") you don't need a shell. Just pass the program's name and the optional arguments:

```
subprocess.check_output(["notepad.exe", "file.txt"])
```

---

BTW, what are you trying to do with the line:

```
subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)
```

This only launch a subshell, asking it to exit immediately with a non-zero status code ?!?

Comment: i was just following the example code they had on the python website, and thanks 
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"], shell=True)
seems to work perfectly, Also do you know to call a command exe while passing in parameters

Comment: @Rohit I'm not accustomed to windows, but I have edited my answer to show you how to launch "notepad.exe". That _should_ work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: thanks sylvain, launching the notepad seems to work fine, but i am trying to call a command exe with some parameters, then i have to wait until it connects to some server, then pass in the login and the password, then pipe the output from the command exe to a file.

Comment: but the answer you provided was perfect for the question i asked. Thanks